# Oozie Bundles: Relaunching a coordinator inside an oozie bundle

Tags: bundle, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Say I have a currently running oozie bundle running coordinators A and B.

I do development work on coordinator B and I want to relaunch coordinator B.

Is there any way to relaunch a coordinator inside of an oozie bundle, without restarting the bundle itself? This is because I don't want to restart coordinator A.

Otherwise, is there a way to add/remove a coordinator from a currently running oozie bundle?